# nodemon server.js is not showing any result (error or success)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

i am running a file server.js using nodemon server.js command but it doesn't response by displaying error or success message. its taking too much time but shows no result? The following messages show by terminal

[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

but it doesn't move forward from here and not even displaying an error message? And i am using mongodb cloud atlas

My server.js file

```
  import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import restuarants from "./api/restuarants.route.js";

const app = express()

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

app.use("/api/v1/restuarants", restuarants)
app.use("*", (req, res) => res.status(404).json({ error: "Not Found"}))

export default app
```

my index.js file

```
  import app from "./server.js"
import mongodb from "mongodb"
import dotenv from "dotenv"

dotenv.config()
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.RESTREVIEW_DB_URI,
    {
        maxPoolSize: 50, 
        wtimeoutMS: 2500,
        useNewUrlParse: true
    }
)
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err.stakc)
    process.exit(1)
})
.then(async client => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
    })
})
```

My router file

```
import express from "express"

const router = express.Router()

router.route("/").get((req, res) => res.send("Hello World"))

export default router
```

Comment: Are you sending a request to the server? Are you logging something on server? Cannot help without more information.

Comment: i have updated my question now you can see

Comment: You say you are running server.js. I think you should be running index.js since you are exporting everything to index.js